# Coefficients in a linear combination general form

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

My book gives the following linear combination of vectors
in an example
**$r(1, 1, 0) +s(1, 0, 1) + t(0, 1, 1) = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$**

It then says that
**$r = \frac{1}{2}(a_1 + a_2 - a_3)$**
**$s = \frac{1}{2}(a_1 - a_2 + a_3)$**
**$t = \frac{1}{2}(-a_1 + a_2 + a_3)$**

I'm confused as to how they actually came up with these equations? I'm lost ; how did they get those values for $r, s, t$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$r(1,1,0)+s(1,0,1)+t(0,1,1)=(r+s,r+t,s+t),$$they just solved the equation $(r+s,r+t,s+t)=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, which is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}r+s=a_1\\r+t=a_2\\s+t=a_3,\end{array}\right.$$whose solutions are $r=\frac12(a_1+a_2-a_3)$, $s=\frac12(a_1-a_2+a_3)$, and $t=\frac12(-a_1+a_2+a_3)$.

Comment: I still don't see where the 1/2 values are coming from.

Comment: From the first and the second equations you get that $s-t=a_1-a_2$. Adding this to the third equation, you'll get $2s=a_1-a_2+a_3$. In other words, $s=\frac12(a_1-a_2+a_3)$.

Comment: Ah okay thank you so much!